# Interference between two signals with the same frequency. (exercise from the book software receiver design)

Tags: software-defined-radio

I find it hard to describe the LPF. This is an exercise from the book [Software Receiver Design
Build Your Own Digital Communications System in Five Easy Steps](https://www.worldcat.org/title/software-receiver-design-build-your-own-digital-communication-system-in-five-easy-steps/oclc/711047830) chapter 4.23.

[image: The problem statement is in the picture.]

[image]

Comment: Hi My_LuLu- I think you will need to explain in more detail what it is you don’t understand and what you are asking.